# Accessing nested JSON file with hash structure

Tags: json, go

I have JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
  "env": {
      "production": {
         "test": {
             "text": "hello"
          },
          "url": {
             "str": "url1"
          }
      },
      "staging": {
         "test": {
             "text": "hel1lo"
          },
          "url": {
             "str": "url31"
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a way to import this file and get into nested struct format just for staging and its inner fields in correct order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to parse the staging data to a Go value:

```
type env struct {
  Test struct {
    Text string
  }
  URL struct {
    Str string
  }
}

var v struct {
  Env struct {
    Staging env
  }
}

err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v)
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}

staging :=  v.Env.Staging
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/s80fqMbEXs)</kbd>

JSON object fields are unordered. The Go standard library does not provide a way to get object fields in source order.

Answer (score 0):

While, I'm not familiar with Go and its JSON facilities JSON objects are specified as unordered.  If you require your input be in a particular order you'll need to use an array.

From json.org:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by , (comma).
>
> An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [
>   (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated
>   by , (comma).